# MmAllocateContiguousMemory default permissions

Tags: windows, winapi, kernel, device-driver

Does anyone know what are the default permissions on the page, returned by this routine. Is there any chance of putting some code section on this page.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no - there is no safe, documented way of manipulating page protection bits from kernel mode.  These bits are owned by the memory manager.

That said, since memory allocated in this fashion does not have the NX bit set, there is nothing to stop you from executing code from memory allocated via this API.

EDIT: I stand corrected - I was unaware of the API mentioned in Alex's answer above.  You learn something new everyday!

Comment: By mistake, I was using one of the page allocated through MmAllocateContiguousMemory as a code page. I was amuzed when I did not see a BSOD. It is weird that windows can alloacate pinned memory with execute permissions. @Alex: Thanks for MDL. However, I wonder why windows allows to execute from allocated pages. Is it because pages are pre-allocated in the page table with NX bit not set.

Answer (score 4):

Allocate memory through an MDL and then call [MmProtectMdlSystemAddress()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554670%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to change the page protection.

Found [here](http://www.winvistatips.com/marking-pages-nonpagedpool-read_only-t789472.html).

Comment: Alex:Do u know if there is a routine to check the permissions on a page which is allocated from non-paged pool.